# Флешбек в Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

После установки Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS x86_64 на ноутбук Lenovo ideapad 100-15IBD с параметрами:

```
Intel i3-5005U (4) @ 1.900GHz;
NVIDIA GeForce 920M;
ОЗУ 4 Гб;
HDD 500 Гб;
```

Начали наблюдаться флешбеки. К примеру, во время воспроизведения видео или общения в Skype/TeamSpeak часть звуковой информации возвращается назад на доли секунды (наблюдалось до 3 раз вподряд), и в итоге сказанное человеком слово может повториться 2-3 раза. Подобная ситуация наблюдается периодически, с частотой 1-2 раза в 30 минут. 
Вот что выдает syslog сразу же после ошибки:

```
Sep  1 12:26:40 Destructor org.gnome.zeitgeist.SimpleIndexer[2377]: ** (zeitgeist-fts:3315): WARNING **: Unable to get info on application://nautilus-autostart.desktop
Sep  1 12:26:44 Destructor AptDaemon: INFO: Quitting due to inactivity
Sep  1 12:26:44 Destructor AptDaemon: INFO: Quitting was requested
Sep  1 12:26:44 Destructor org.freedesktop.PackageKit[826]: 12:26:44 AptDaemon [INFO]: Quitting due to inactivity
Sep  1 12:26:44 Destructor org.freedesktop.PackageKit[826]: 12:26:44 AptDaemon [INFO]: Quitting was requested
```

Я заметил, что каждый раз после этой ошибки возникает сообщение:

```
Destructor org.gnome.zeitgeist.SimpleIndexer[2377]: ** (zeitgeist-fts:3315): WARNING **: Unable to get info on application://nautilus-autostart.desktop
```

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться и исправить данную ситуацию, я только начал знакомство с Ubuntu.

Comment: мне кажется, что с подобными вещами лучше обращаться к разработчикам данного клиента. В целом скайп у меня и на винде не лучше работает..

Comment: Маловероятно, что указанная Вами ошибка связана с записью в логе. Запись в логе приложении не связанном со звуком напрямую. Попробуйте воспользоваться htop для наблюдения за ресурсами во время возникновения проблемы.

Comment: Хочу обратить внимание, что данная ситуация происходит не только при работе клиентов Skype/TeamSpeak, а и при воспроизведении видео в браузере. Также, в момент флешбека система подвисает на это же время.

Comment: Попробуйте найти, где у вас этот nautilus-autostart.desktop находится и удалить его (по идее в ~/.config/autostart, но возможно ~/.local/share/applications или /usr/share/applications).

Comment: Похоже что на этом файле запинается zeitgeist - сервис индексирования используемых юзером файлов. Смотрите в системный монитор когда это происходит.